# In Google Spreasheet, how do I reference to a cell value from the Chart editor?

Tags: google-sheets, google-visualization

I am creating a line chart that contains multiple data series. In the picture below I'm showing the Chart editor of this line chart:

[image: Chart editor]

Every time I need to add more rows, I have to change manually the "400" value in each series. I am wondering if there is a way to create a reference to a certain cell value, so that I can just edit that cell value and have the "400" replaced with that cell value everywhere. Thank you.

Comment: Your data range mixes various ranges of different heights, starting either from row 11 or 12, and ending on row 84 or 85. The order of subranges also seems haphazard. It might be easier to use a `query()` to create a clean table with columns in the order you want in the chart. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the range references one row taller, e.g., `V11:V401`, and insert new rows between rows `400` and `401`.

Alternatively, delete all rows below row `400`. The chart will automatically add new rows as they are inserted at the bottom of the sheet.